# How does $|00\rangle$ evolve through an Hadamard and a CNOT gate?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-circuit

If we have this given circuit:
[image: circuit 1]
So the output for $|0\rangle$ will be: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|00\rangle + |11\rangle\right)$
And we have this given circuit:
[image]
What will be the output for $|00\rangle$ and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hadamard gate is its own inverse. Hence, the two Hadamards on the first qubit cancel, leaving the control qubit in state $|0 \rangle$.
The bottom Hadamard gate will put the target qubit in the state $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|0\rangle + |1\rangle)$.
Since the control qubit is still in state $|0\rangle$, the CNOT will do nothing to the target. Your output state is therefore
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|00\rangle + |01\rangle)$.